# Start TWO node scripts simultaniously in one docker container

Tags: node.js, docker

Is something like this possible to run two node.js scripts in one docker container?

```
docker run -d --name nt -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app node node 2.js && node 1.js
```

Neither this:

```
docker run -d --name nt -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app node node 2.js node 1.js
```

Or is this something that is not meant to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `&` instead of `&&`. One `&` means "send the command to background".
Second, use quotes in order to tell bash to not interpret the `&`, and leave the interpretation to the shell inside the container.
Third use 'sh -c' to group the commands (optional).

Do this:

```
docker run -d --name nt -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app node sh -c 'node 2.js & node 1.js'
```

---

However I recommend to use `supervisor` to get a more robust solution:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/

Comment: Or combining the two scripts into one.

Comment: @robertklep, yes. Good lateral thinking. But sometimes you need to run two or more *parallel* blocking processes (although node is good for that as is single threaded)

Comment: thanks, i think you forgot to define the image in your command "node"